# How to prevent access to ASMX web service

Tags: ajax, web-services

I have a web service that is being invoked by an ajax call in the JavaScript of my page, but when users view the source, they can see the path to the ASMX file, which they can type into the address bar. I want users to be restricted in viewing and/or accessing the methods of this web service. I want only the JavaScript file to be able to use those methods. Is this possible? These users are not behind any log in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to proxy the commands through another service? Or just obfuscate the code so they can't see what the URLs of the service are?

Comment: Use client-side certs to prevent access to the server, or enable windows authenication and prevent access at the filesystem level.

Comment: Or.. if you're just worried about users being to see the help page, [see this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2tyf2t8t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You shouldn't be worried about users knowing your webservices URL, but you should protect what you return with a logged in key or something provided by your website.

The rule is: you don't want people to do something? Check that before on the server side and then return "you are not authorized" or another access error. Even if you try to do a very good job in your JS, it is very easy to monitor what you are accessing with the browser debug features: press F12.

Comment: Your first statement of "You can't" is incorrect, and likely to garner a downvote. The rest of your answer has the right sentiment, but isn't really an answer to the OP's question (more of a sidenote).

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I believe the question is about the JS source code and to hide its URL to the server, not the server source code. So I don't see how come this to be inaccurate.